# Graph API is not showing all revelant wall posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I´m currently working on a project for one of my customers. I have a problem regarding the graph api. I trying to receive all news feeds by calling
    http://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/feed?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN.
The access token is valid and active. The customers page also allowed the app to use the read_stream permission. But I only receive a single post published in April, although the customer posted many in June. Is it a bug? I tried it on the graph api explorer on facebook - same result. I also tried it with my own account - everything works fine.

Need help!

Comment: What does a call to `/me/permissions` show? What type of posts aren't appearing, are the posts from the page itself or from users on the page?

Comment: The Result: "installed": 1, "read_stream": 1. The post is from the customer. In the privacy I found out that it is a hidden post? See this:
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Only Me", 
        "value": "SELF", 
        "allow": "0", 
        "deny": "0"
      },

Comment: Only Me isn't 'hidden' - it's just visible only to the person that posted it, you should be able to see these when acting on behalf of the user who posted them

Comment: okay. but i´m still unable to receive the whole feeds. why?

Comment: I submitted a bug report. hopefully its gonna be fixed soon.